# SQL query - SELECT in SUM

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I need SUM of results of SELECT query. When I don't use SUM, it shows me this result:

```
        CELKOVA_CENA
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
80
80
120
120
120
80
150
80
150
120
150
120
.
.
.
```

But when I use SUM function, it shows me error:

> ORA-00936: missing expression

Please, how can I fix it?

```
SELECT SUM (
   SELECT n.hodnota 
   FROM evidn_nastaveni n
   WHERE n.popis = 'cena_krakorce'
   AND
   n.upresneni = k.pozice) 
   AS celkova_cena
FROM (
  SELECT oc.clen, oc.oddil
  FROM evidn_oddily_clenove oc 
  INNER JOIN evidn_oddily o ON oc.oddil = o.id
  WHERE o.nazev = 'Slalom')
NATURAL JOIN evidn_krakorce k;
```

Thanks for responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think below approach should give result as per your expectation -

```
SELECT SUM(celkova_cena)
  from (select (SELECT n.hodnota
                  FROM evidn_nastaveni n
                 WHERE n.popis = 'cena_krakorce'
                   AND n.upresneni = k.pozice) AS celkova_cena
          FROM (SELECT oc.clen, oc.oddil
                  FROM evidn_oddily_clenove oc
                 INNER JOIN evidn_oddily o
                    ON oc.oddil = o.id
                 WHERE o.nazev = 'Slalom') NATURAL
          JOIN evidn_krakorce k);
```

You need to cross check that you don't have duplicate value in `evidn_nastaveni` table (which is getting used in inner query) for having `popis = 'cena_krakorce' and upresneni = evidn_krakorce .pozice`.

If so, then you need to use any aggregate function (MIN/MAX/ SUM) in inner query.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your specific problem by putting the `sum()` in the subquery:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(n.hodnota)
        FROM evidn_nastaveni n
         WHERE n.popis = 'cena_krakorce' AND
               n.upresneni = k.pozice) 
       ) celkova_cena
FROM . . .
```

Comment: thanks for your response. But it not fix it. Your solution makes, that a query makes SUM on each of rows. So it seems like this:

  CELKOVA_CENA
--------
SUM(80)
SUM(80)
SUM(120)
SUM(120)
SUM(120)
SUM(80)
SUM(150)
SUM(80)
SUM(150)
SUM(120)
SUM(150)
SUM(120)
.
.
.


The result is same. I need sum all of values together.

But thanks for your response. Do you have any another idea?